# A σ-structure is called rigid if it has no σ -automorphisms other than the identity. Show the structures $(N,0,S,+,·)$ and $(Q,0,1,+,·)$ are rigid.

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

An σ-isomorphism is a σ-homomorphism that has a 2-sided inverse , which is also a σ-homomorphism. For $(N,0,S,+,·)$ to be rigid, it would mean that it has a 2-sided inverse (other than the identity). For $(Q,0,1,+,·)$ to be rigid, it would mean that it has a 2-sided inverse (other than the identity). That is impossible in both cases. However I'm having a hard time proving it. It's pretty easy to prove the contrary ie. giving an example of an σ-automorphism other than the identity. But, now we need to prove that ALL possible functions will never work. For $(N,0,S,+,·)$ im thinking it might have something to do with S, the successor as maybe the relation will not be respected.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb N$ note that an automorphism $f$ necessarily has $f(0)=0$. Furthermore, $f(S(0))=S(f(0))=1$. Similarly, $f(2)=S(f(1))=2$. You can then use induction to prove that $f(n)=n$ for all $n$.

Now let's consider $\mathbb Q$ and an automorphism $f$. Now, $f(1)=1$ so $f(2)=f(1)+f(1)=2$. Similarly to above, induction tells us that $f$ is the identity on $\mathbb N$. We claim now that $f(-n)=-n$ for any natural $n$. Indeed, $f(0)=0$ so $0=f(n+ (-n))=f(n)+f(-n)=n+f(-n)$. Thus, $f(-n)= -n$ so we have that $f$ is the identity on $\mathbb Z$. Now let's consider some rational number $a/b$. Then $f(a/b)b=f(a)=a$, as $a \in \mathbb Z$. Thus, $f(a/b) = a/b$ and $f$ is the identity.